# ios warning: could not find referenced DIE

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I use Crashlytics in My project. When I set `Debug information format` debug and release in `DWARF with dsym file`. It will appear a warning: `could not find referenced DIE`.  something wrong with  `Geth` lib. How to  fix  this warning. I need a  help.

[image: Detail info]

Comment: It's a DWARF issue, that's for sure.

Comment: Thanks. Are you building a completely native app or using something like React? I'd like to determine the cause of this issue :)

Comment: native app, also this warn just appear by use simulator